# How to choose only one column of a Matrix of plots in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, plot

so, i've got a data.frame which is 6*4500 here is an example of the first three lines and columns:

```
1912.5000   4246.6053   5543.7895
2080.6667   2484.7333   3317.6333
531.6667    4131.1000   5286.9000
```

when i use:

```
plot(df)
```

i get a matrix scatter plots.

- i.e., x vs y and x vs z is the first column.
- y vs x, and y vs z is the second column
- z vs x, and z vs y is the third column.

[image: example]

the example is for the full dataframe, just three first columns. 
ignore the missing x and y, i cut them off, they exist...

my question is how can i plot just the first column. meaning, X vs y and X vs z
in theory i can do it with a loop and subplot. i prefer to make it efficient.

Comment: As in `plot(df$x, df$y)`?

Comment: Alternatively, try `library(reshape2); library(ggplot2); ggplot(melt(df, id.vars = "x"), aes(x=x, y=value)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("variable")`

Comment: Coffeinjunky, that would give me only x vs y. i want x vs z as well, and x vs p etc (6 columns). as for the second suggestion, i'm not sure what it does... i understand it combines the values somehow... can you clarify?

Comment: See my post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df <- mtcars[,1:4]
head(df)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105
```

Here is what you don't want:

```
plot(df)
```

[image]

Now, to easily produce grouped or facetted graphs, `ggplot2` is probably the package you want to use. `ggplot2` requires you to pass a dataframe in long format, which is achieved by `melt`ing the dataframe first, keeping your `x` variable as `id` variable. This means you are essentially "stacking" the columns on top of each other, repeating the id-variable and keeping a reference to which column it originally belonged. Here I use the `mtcars` dataset as an example, where `x` is miles per hour or `mpg`.

```
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = "mpg")
head(df2)
   mpg variable value
1 21.0      cyl     6
2 21.0      cyl     6
3 22.8      cyl     4
4 21.4      cyl     6
5 18.7      cyl     8
6 18.1      cyl     6

tail(df2)
    mpg variable value
91 26.0       hp    91
92 30.4       hp   113
93 15.8       hp   264
94 19.7       hp   175
95 15.0       hp   335
96 21.4       hp   109
```

Having this kind of dataframe, you can plot use e.g.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=mpg, y=value)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap("variable", scales="free)
```

to obtain one graph for each group / initial column.

[image]

Comment: this is great. thank you coffeinjunky. still below 15rep, so i can't upvote :(